# Rails - Plug facebook & twitter account and share

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, share

I tried different method to plug, for users in my web app, social account and share data ( status and images etc. )

In my process I've seen that there is many way to do that, like:

- `oauth`
- many different gems
- etc.

So I would like to have your feedback of what you've used to do that. Plug and social account for users on your web app.

I would like to do that with a easy way, because I have to go fast. 
(But I'm also interest by the good/better/optimised way for future optimisation.)

I'm all ears ! thanks

Comment: Did you check omniauth gem? It provides multi provider authentication
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth